# FastReport.Net. Error at registering data

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting, fastreport

According to FastReport.Net documentation the RegisterData method is overloaded and I can register data several ways. I try to register **dataset** by next code:

```
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT t.* FROM test t";
        ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        report1.Load("report1.frx");
        report1.RegisterData(ds, "user_ds");
        report1.GetDataSource("user_ds").Enabled = true;  //Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        ((DataBand)report1.FindObject("Data1")).DataSource = report1.GetDataSource("user_ds");

        report1.Show();
```

and get error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But I get success when register **data table**:

```
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT t.* FROM test t";
        ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "test");

        report1.Load("report1.frx");
        report1.RegisterData(ds.Tables["test"], "user_ds");
        report1.GetDataSource("user_ds").Enabled = true;
        ((DataBand)report1.FindObject("Data1")).DataSource = report1.GetDataSource("user_ds");

        report1.Show();
```

Why I can't register **dataset**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *table* name in the `GetDataSource` method.

For example:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add("test");
report1.RegisterData(ds, "user_ds");
report1.GetDataSource("test").Enabled = true; // "test", not "user_ds"
```

Comment: I got error "(GroupHeader1): Error CS1525: Invalid expression term '['" for your code... but I have single TextObject on GroupHeader1 with "[Date]" and for my code it's work

Comment: see [FastReport.Net. Registration of dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179788/fastreport-net-registration-of-dataset)